# Dynamics ax Report watermark in TEST and DEV systems

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2012

could you please give me some advice or example (maintenance free) on how I put  a watermark (or something similar) in a report ( for example salesInvoice) which is created from a DEV or TEST system.

The idea is that I will use a background image in a Report and the value will be given by tmpTable which is feeded by a DP class and until there I am good. but some how I have to identify that the system is not the production system in order to add (or do not add) the value of the path of the background image in my report.

Theoritically I can take the AOS name through code and compare it with a list of production AOS instances, but I am afraid that if a new production AOS instance come at future then this solution is not maintenance free, which means someone has to remeber this list and add the name of the new AOS instance. otherwise I guess all reports produced by this  new PROD AOS instance will have this watermark.

Thanks in advance,
Nikos.

Comment: Could you just do something simple like replacing the company name with `CompanyName+Dev`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? sorry I do not get it.

Comment: When you print a report, the company name `Contoso, Inc` for example is displayed on the header/footer somewhere usually. You can change the AX code so that when the call to `CompanyInfo` is returned, you return `Contoso, Inc - TEST` and it prints on the report. Just a different idea that may be easier to solve.